# Alphanumeric auto-increment id in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to have alphanumeric auto-increment id in Oracle. I have read one of the post here and applied that too. But I am getting only numeric ID.

I want my LAWYERID to be in a format like LAWYER0000001,LAWYER0000002 and so on.

```
//my table is:

 SQL>   CREATE TABLE  "LAWYERS" 
   ( "LAWYERID" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     "NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     "EXPERTISE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     "MOBILE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     "FEES" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     "VERIFIED" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     "TEMP_ID" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     CONSTRAINT "LAWYERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LAWYERID") ENABLE
   ) ;
```

Here is the trigger that I have created for table name lawyers:

```
SQL>   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "LAWYERS_TRIG" 
BEFORE INSERT ON lawyers 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT lawyers_sequ1.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.lawyerid
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

This is the sequence:

```
SQL>    CREATE SEQUENCE   "LAWYERS_SEQU1"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 
9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER  
NOCYCLE ;
```

Comment: Stop and think about the purpose of the ID and why you need that format.

Comment: You are working on a project and the deadline is near? I assume you are paid for it? This is a free, volunteer forum; if you must meet a deadline, perhaps you should find paid help. And you should work on projects for which you possess the needed expertise and experience. Best of luck!

Comment: If you need this for cosmetic purposes, just use a standard sequence, and render the prefix before the sequence whenever you display it to the user.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can check vote the right answer below so that this inquiry will be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
'LAWYER'||TO_CHAR(lawyers_sequ1.NEXTVAL,'FM0000000')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this in your query.

```
   SELECT 'LAWYER'+ REPLACE(STR(LAWYERID, 7), SPACE(1), '0') FROM LAWYERS
```

Usally, in tables auto-increment systems are numeric. Also you can write trigger for this. It's look like this.

```
 DECLARE @INTNEWID INT
 DECLARE @LASTID VARCHAR(13)
 DECLARE @NEWID VARCHAR(13)
 SET @LASTID=( SELECT TOP 1 LAWYERID
               FROM LAWYERS ORDER BY LAWYERID DESC)
 SET @INTLASTID=CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@LASTID,0,6))+1 
 SET @NEWID ='LAWYER'+ REPLACE(STR(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@INTNEWID),7),SPACE(1), '0') 
 UPDATE LAWYERS SET LAWYERID=@NEWID WHERE LAWYERID=(SELECT TOP 1 LAWYERID FROM INSERTED)
```

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle - this appears to be an SQL Server answer and the syntax is completely different.